# Contenteditable placeholder needs to be empty when saved

Tags: javascript, angularjs

At the company I work at, we took over a project made with symfony2 and angular.js.
It is a platform containing courses. These courses are actually "books", that are made interactive with videos and places to discuss course content.

A course consists of a number of chapters, each with a set of pages.
The person who developed this in angular, used div with contenteditable attributes to enter text. (see screenshot here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXkr7.jpg ) The divs also have a sk-placeholder attribute.

I know the basics to angular and I presumed the sk-placeholder attribute was a directive, replacing the content of the div with some text. Appearently, the contenteditable is the directive using the attribute sk-placeholder's content, to fill the element. (in this case a div).

When in an editable element, if you press enter, the content is saved. If however, you don't fill in anything, the placeholder text is not removed and it is presumed the content of the specific section of the page you're working on. (I hope I am clear enough, if there are any questions please do ask). It should clear the content of all divs with attribute "contenteditable" by default when saving. And that's the part I can't seem to figure out.

```
SEK.app.directive('contenteditable', function($location, sekApi, $q){
       return {
       require: 'ngModel',
       restrict: 'A',
       link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {

        var richText = attrs.richText || false,
            focused = false;

        function renderMath () {
            if(richText) {
                var math = element[0];
                MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,math]);
            }
        }

        function renderElement() {
            if(!ctrl.$viewValue && attrs.skPlaceholder) {
                element.addClass("sk-placeholding");
                element.html(attrs.skPlaceholder);
            } else {
                element.removeClass("sk-placeholding");
                element.html(ctrl.$viewValue);
                renderMath();
            }
        }

        ctrl.$render = function() {
            renderElement();
        };


        element[0].onpaste = function(e) {
            var pastedText = undefined;
            if (window.clipboardData && window.clipboardData.getData) { // IE
                pastedText = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
            } else if (e.clipboardData && e.clipboardData.getData) {
                pastedText = e.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
            }

            SEK.utilities.insertTextAtCursor(pastedText);
            // Prevent the default handler from running.
            return false;
        };

        element.bind('focus', function () {
            element.html(ctrl.$viewValue || "");
            element.removeClass("sk-placeholding");
            focused = true;
        });

        element.bind('blur', function(event) {
            var newViewValue = false;
            if(element.html().length > 0){
                var htmlContent = element.html();
                htmlContent = htmlContent.replace(/<div><br><\/div>/g, "<br>");
                htmlContent = htmlContent.replace(/<div><br \/><\/div>/g, "<br>");
                htmlContent = htmlContent.replace(/<div>/g, "<br>");
                htmlContent = htmlContent.replace(/<\/div>/g, "");
                newViewValue = htmlContent;
            }

            if(element.html().length == 0 && attrs.skPlaceholder) {
                newViewValue = "";
            };

            if(typeof newViewValue === "string") {
                scope.$apply(function() {
                    ctrl.$setViewValue(newViewValue);
                });
            }

            renderElement();

            focused = false;
        });

        element.bind('keydown', function(event) {
            var esc = event.which == 27,
                enter = event.which == 13,
                el = event.target;

            if(!richText && esc) {
                element.html(ctrl.$viewValue);
                el.blur();
                event.preventDefault();
            }

            if (esc || (!richText && enter)) {
                scope.ngModel = element.html();
                el.blur();
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    }
}
});
```

Any questions are more than welcome. Please do note that I'm a novice when it comes to Angular.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On save check:

```
attrs.skPlaceholder === element.html() || attrs.skPlaceholder === element.text()
```

if this expression returns true, the element seems to be empty.

Or you may check:

```
element.hasClass("sk-placeholding")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That is indeed a nice way to do it. Unfortunately my interpretation of the code was wrong. The placeholder is not getting saved into the database. But when you switch from author view to student view, the page is not being rendered again, thus keeping the placeholder in the div. I need to make some changing in the switch view statement. But thanks anyway :)